# Do ripe bananas combat abnormal cells and cancer?

Tags: medical-science, cancer, fruit

> According to Japanese Scientific Research, full ripe banana with dark patches on yellow skin produces a substance called TNF (Tumor Necrosis Factor) which has the ability to combat abnormal cells. The more darker patches it has the higher will be its immunity enhancement quality; Hence, the riper the banana the better the anti-cancer quality. Yellow skin banana with dark spots on it is 8x more effective in enhancing the property of white blood cells than green skin version.
>   Eating 1-2 banana/s a day increases immunity.
>   Please pass/share and stay healthy.
>
> Hoax or Fact:
>
> **Fact.**

Source: [Hoax or Fact](http://www.hoaxorfact.com/Health/full-ripe-banana-with-dark-patches-combats-abnormal-cells-and-cancer.html)

While many Internet sites state that it is a myth, it is weird to see some hoax-slaying websites supporting it.

How true is the article? Does Tumor Necrosis Factor(TNF-α) really matter?